# Aggregate Action with CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, nsexpression

I have a CoreData "data base" and to simplify let's say that my objects have two attributes: a variable name and a variable value. I want to aggregate the content of the DB by "variable name" ("GROUP BY") and for each of the variables "names" , I want to find the standard deviation of the variables value. To do so, I use a NSExpression: 
expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "valeur_nombre.@stddev")

The issue is that I get the following error:

> [error] CoreData: Exception was caught during
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator -performBlock: Can't generate select
>   target token for expression: valeur_nombre.@stddev with userInfo
>   (null)

I have try to use the same code with different "aggregate action":
-count
-sum
-max
-min 
with no issues. However when I try to compute the average like writing in the Apple Docs:
expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "valeur_nombre.@average")

I get this error :

> [error] CoreData: Exception was caught during
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator -performBlock: Can't generate select
>   target token for expression: valeur_nombre.@average with userInfo
>   (null)

If I replace "average" by "avg":
expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(format: "valeur_nombre.@avg")
Then I got the right result 
Unfortunately, I didn't find any workaround for:
-median
-stddev

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Try NSExpression(format: “stddev:( valeur_nombre)”).

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I get the following error: CoreData: Exception was caught during NSPersistentStoreCoordinator -performBlock: Unsupported function type passed to SQL store with userInfo {
    "Bad value" = "stddev:(valeur_nombre)";
}

Comment: It seems that stddev is not supported by Core Data SQLite store. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html I have to load first the data in memory but I have a lot of data I don’t know the most efficient way to proceed